# Reasonable good way to use the aws sdk version 2 in java, to request the apigateway

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sdk, aws-api-gateway

Java SDK in version 2 provides lots of clients for different services, but we would like to have everything centralized in the api gateway for control reasons. The goal of the implementation I am working with is to have most or all requests in one place/have a factory giving back a caller to the apigateway, where you can set timeout etc.

I can't really find an example in the documentation, for version 2, how this should or could be implemented. Having an HttpClient that has the AWS-Credentials that can call the Api-Gateway Endpoint.
It was possible to have a client like that in aws sdk v1, but the migration to v2 failed pretty miserably, which makes me feel, like this was an unwanted implementation.

Or is the best way to generate a custom SDK from the api gateway?